# When is a group of attributes considered prime?

Tags: database-design

Given the candidate keys CD and DE and the functional dependency AB->CDE. Is CDE considered prime because all attributes (C, D and E) are prime? Or is it non-prime because CDE is not found in a candidate key as a whole?
Therefore, my question is if a group of prime attributes is also prime due to its attributes or it has to be part of a candidate key as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I recently received the right answer for my question from my professor, so I will leave it here in case anyone will ever need it.

ANSWER: CDE is prime because C,D and E are individually prime. If the attributes of a group are prime, then the group is also prime (the group does not have to be part of a candidate key as a whole).